# Why might DMS become more apparent toward the end of a keg?

Tags: dms

I brewed a keg of witbier for a wedding, and when I tasted it initially, as well as at the wedding, I did not notice a prominent DMS note. I am now drinking a glass and the DMS is nearly overwhelming. This is the very last bit of a keg that was kept warm for a day or so after the wedding.

Does exposure to oxygen increase the presence of DMS? The keg was dispensed with CO2, but there is always some O2 picked up on transfer, I suppose.

Comment: I wouldn't think oxygen would play a role, since I'm pretty sure DMSO (dimethyl sulf*oxide*) is the flavorless compound to which DMS is converted.

Comment: Infact the problem could be the reduction of DMSO to DMS. Both DMSO and DMS are produced from SMM in the boil. DMSO has a boiling point of 189 °C so is not nearly as volitile as DMS. During fermentation DMSO can be reduced to DMS.

Answer (score 2):

I think the heat maybe accentuated the smell.

But, DMS can also be from biological contamination. Considering that the keg was warmer, the bugs would have been in a better environment.